# Byte ordering of protocol number in raw packets

Tags: python, networking

On Internet I found multiple occurrences of following code snippets.

```
ETH_P_ALL=0x0003 # from /usr/include/linux/if_ether.h
sock=socket.socket( socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.ntohs( ETH_P_ALL))
```

and

```
ETH_P_IP=0x0800 # from /usr/include/linux/if_ether.h
sock=socket.socket( socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, ETH_P_IP)
```

Why do we need to change byte-ordering for ETH_P_ALL?
Do Python include the byte-swap (htons) internally? If yes , the first snippet would be wrong.

Comment: Maybe they are both wrong. I'm not an expert on AF_PACKET, so am only making a comment. But looking at the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/packet.7.html): _protocol is the IEEE 802.3 protocol number in network byte order_, meaning they should both use `socket.htons`.

Comment: @tdelaney I would say that one or the other is wrong. The problem is that we don't know if htons() in included in the python code of socket(). And python documentation is very terse (can I also say 'inadequate') about raw packets.